# How to avoid flash of unmedia'd content with respond.js

Tags: internet-explorer, media-queries, respond.js

I am using [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) in IE9+ when Document Mode is set to IE8, as my IE9+ stylesheets contain media queries (mobile first), and those get pulled in under IE8 Document Mode since Browser Mode is still set to IE9.

I've included respond.js via a script tag as early as possible in the head, immediately following my stylesheets. However, I see a flash of unmedia'd content for about a quarter second when loading the page in IE9 with Document Mode set to IE8.

Is there any to prevent the flash?